# Python Selenium Import from different location

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do web automation using python and selenium in my office laptop. Because of which I cannot install the selenium module. It requires admin privileges which I cannot obtain for some reason.

I have downloaded the selenium-3.141.0.tar & selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl packages too and have it under the C:\Users\office_username\Downloads\selenium\ location. And my Python 3.5 is installed in the windows location C:\Program Files\Python\Python35.

If I have to create a simple python file like below, Im sure it would fail.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser=webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

How to do I get this working. I cannot use pip install, as its office laptop, it has firewall, proxy and blocks connection and installation fails.

Is there a way I can point to the another directory and get this working, Please advise.

Comment: Please create a python virtual environment in your user space and install any packages in the new virtual environment.
Reference:
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
- https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Alternatively you can extract the libraries from wheel/egg files and add the directory to PYTHONPATH to allow loading from it:
- https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/17/extract-python-egg-and-wheel/

Comment: Thanks @Sharad. I was able to achieve this with venv. Once I activated the env, I downloaded the selenium whl and urllib3 whl files and installed it in the env, it worked. But there are still HKEY issues, which is beyond my control. Cannot perform registry changes at all... Thank you !!!

Comment: Glad it helped!